# Filter ListView with ArrayAdapter contain string

Tags: android, arrays, listview, filter, adapter

i'm making a dictionary. I want to filter search word with the search textbox.
Here the example:

```
Ame(雨)
飴(Ame)
```

But when i type into the textbox "ame", only Ame(雨) is show.
I want both words show. Here my code:

I load all the word into ArrayList "wordlist"

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, wordList);

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible from default filter behavior. You could write your own custom logic.

This article might help you http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: Yes, I thought about making custom adapter too. Thank you